# Django Extending model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm just wanting to know how to extend a model in Django without needing to create new database tables or rows.

I have two models. SSALi with a unique ticker and date, and NELi with a ticker and a date that are together unique. I want a model or function called  NN_feed that has all of the attributes of both models,EG sentiment, and prediction.

The below works but it has created a new table that I need to join for every row and date.

Is there a way to do this without extra database tables and just pull from the existing data?

Just to be clear, the SSALiReport and NELiReport databases need to stay the same. I just want to pull the data into a third model and just view all the data in one place.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.

class SSALiReport(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='NA')
    market = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='NA')

    price = models.FloatField()
    prediction = models.FloatField()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + " - " + str(self.ticker)


class NELiReport(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='NA')
    sentiment = models.FloatField(default='0.0')
    clout = models.FloatField(default='0.0')
    top_news = JSONField(default='{}')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + " - " + str(self.ticker)

class TopStock(models.Model):

    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='NA')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='NA')
    current_price = models.FloatField(default='0.0')
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    # need to add company name

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + " - " + str(self.ticker)


class NNFeed(models.Model):

    NELi = models.OneToOneField(NELi_Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    SSALi = models.OneToOneField(SSALi_Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this SQL script works

```
SELECT *
FROM api_neli_report, api_ssali_report
WHERE api_neli_report.ticker = api_ssali_report.ticker
AND api_neli_report.date =  api_ssali_report.date
```

what is the django equivalent?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also what is the name of your last model? You are currently *not* extending any models, but if you do, setting `abstract` to `True` prevents it from creating separate tables. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: Where are you going to place the fields EG sentiment, and prediction if you won't create a new table?

Comment: Follow the Python coding conventions as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It hurts my eyes when I read the code. Class names should be in `PascalCase` - `NELiReport` instead of `NELi_Report`; attribute names are in `snake_case` - `current_price` instead of  `currentPrice`.

Comment: Hey Alexandr the (SSALi_Report, NELi_Report) are existing reports for other reasons. Rather than creating a database table when I have all of the data currently. I want to just pull it as in an object.

Comment: Just curious. Do you want the child model to both read and write the base models or just reading?

Comment: Also, did you try proxy models https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models?

Comment: I think I'm going to need to do this via the view.py with a join on NELiReport.objects.all() and SSALiReport.objects.all(). But the NNReport (in the view now) will need to have all of the attributes.  I'm trying to workout how to do the join

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this same issue see below for how I resolved it.

Just did it via the view using raw sql

```
qs = SSALi_Report.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM api_neli_report, api_ssali_report 
                               WHERE api_neli_report.ticker = api_ssali_report.ticker 
                               AND api_neli_report.date =  api_ssali_report.date")

for row in qs:
   output = {
      "date": row.date,
      "market": row.market,
      "prediction": row.prediction,
      "price": row.price,
      "ticker": row.ticker,
      "clout": row.clout,
      "sentiment": row.sentiment

    }

 return output
```